Can you glue the Betti $X_\text B$ and de Rham stacks $X_\text{dR}$ together?
Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety. Is there a (derived prestack) over a base
$$\pi\ :\ X_\text{dR,B}\ \to\ S$$
where $S=\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{R}^\times,\mathbf{A}^1_\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{G}_m$ or similar,  such that its fibre over the origin is $X_\text{dR}$ and its fibre elsewhere is $X_\text B$?

Notes: 1.
This question is related to but not answered by Scholze's notes Geometrization of the real local Langlands correspondence. 2. I would like “parallel transport along fibres of $\pi$” to induce Riemann–Hilbert. This rules out stupid solutions to the above problem like taking the disjoint union of the two stacks.  3. This is somewhat analogous to Simpson's nonabelian Hodge theory, where there is constructed an algebraic stack $X_H$ over $\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbf{C}}/\mathbf{G}_m$ whose fibre above the origin is $X_\text{Dol}$ and elsewhere is $X_\text{dR}$.

Not sure what you mean by $X_{\mathrm{dR}}^{\mathrm{an}}$. I do not see anywhere in Scholze's note that the analytification of the algebraic de Rham stack is the analytic de Rham stack (I do not know how to define analytification of stacks, either).

@Z.M This is II.3.1 in those linked notes.

It is different: in his notes, he talks about the analytic de Rham stack, which is not constructed out of the algebraic de Rham stack.

This would give an $\mathbf R^\times$ action on $X_{\operatorname{dR}}$, but I don't see any reason for such an action to exist.

@WillSawin Perhaps the author would be happy enough with an analog of the Hodge stack, which lives over $\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{G}_m$.

@WillSawin Good point, I guess that rules out $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{R}^\times$.

@Gabriel I've edited the question to indicate that I'd be happy with any similar base, I don't have any strong preference for one over the other.

@Z.M Whoops, I misread Scholze's notes, you're right. Removed that part of the question.

I think that's a really cool idea, would be great to see a direct relation.. but 1. in a suitable analytic version (cf Scholze's notes) the Betti and de Rham stack are literally isomorphic so no need for this family. In general is there a sense in which X_dR is more degenerate / X_B has something like a filtration? 2. In algebraic geometry they are of very different nature (unlike DR and Dol)- in particular the Betti stack is defined over the integers for example while the de Rham stack is defined over whatever X is. 3. what does parallel transport mean here?

@DavidBen-Zvi 1. I agree we need to use the algebraic de Rham stack here. I don't know the answer to that, but maybe this remark could be useful: my (probably naive) guess is that 3d Chern-Simons with WZW boundary, on (an algebraic curve X) x [0,∞), has something to do with QCoh(X_{dR,B}). Do you know if there is a kind of filtration structure on the differential equations defining CS with boundary? 2. Good point, so probably the fibre away from zero should be the basechange of X_B to Spec C. 3. I just meant that if \pi^an were trivial you get X_dR^an ≅ X_B - I should have called it sth else.

I am having trouble seeing the intuition behind the existence of such a degeneration. To make things more concrete, let's take $X=E$ to be an elliptic curve, and consider the moduli $Pic(E_{dR,B})$ of invertible QC sheaves. If I understand correctly, this would be (ignoring stackiness) a family of algebraic varieties over your $S$, with generic fiber the affine variety $\C^\times \times \C^\times$, and special fiber the moduli of flat line bundles over $E$ (which is an affine bundle over $E$). These fibers are analytically isomorphic but not algebraically. Can such a (nontrivial) family exist?

@DavidBen-Zvi In analytic setting, the "different nature" that you mentioned also exists in Scholze's identification (there is a typo in his notes: he should replace the Betti stack by its base change to gaseous complex numbers — so it is also over the base of definition, instead of integers).
